# For a codimension $>1$ subvariety, the projection from a general point is birational.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a subvariety of codimension $>1$ in  $\mathbb{P}^n$. Show that the projection from a general point is birational.

Comment: Have you tried the case of  $X$ a line in 3-space?

Comment: What I meant was the general point can not be on $X$ to start with.  The second fact is that in your case by counting dimensions, through a general point, all lines can not be secants.